# How to decorate an asyncio.coroutine to retain its __name__?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, coroutine, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I've tried to write a decorator function which wraps an `asyncio.coroutine` and returns the time it took to get done. The recipe below contains the code which is working as I expected. My only problem with it that somehow I loose the name of the decorated function despite the use of `@functools.wraps`. How to retain the name of the original coroutine? I checked the source of `asyncio.`

```
import asyncio
import functools
import random
import time

MULTIPLIER = 5

def time_resulted(coro):
    @functools.wraps(coro)
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
        time_before = time.time()
        result = yield from coro(*args, **kargs)
        if result is not None:
            raise TypeError('time resulted coroutine can '
                'only return None')
        return time_before, time.time()
    print('= wrapper.__name__: {!r} ='.format(wrapper.__name__))
    return wrapper

@time_resulted
@asyncio.coroutine
def random_sleep():
    sleep_time = random.random() * MULTIPLIER
    print('{} -> {}'.format(time.time(), sleep_time))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [asyncio.Task(random_sleep()) for i in range(5)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
    for task in tasks:
        print(task, task.result()[1] - task.result()[0])
    print('= random_sleep.__name__: {!r} ='.format(
        random_sleep.__name__))
    print('= random_sleep().__name__: {!r} ='.format(
        random_sleep().__name__))
```

The result:

```
= wrapper.__name__: 'random_sleep' =
1397226479.00875 -> 4.261069174838891
1397226479.00875 -> 0.6596335046471768
1397226479.00875 -> 3.83421163259601
1397226479.00875 -> 2.5514027672929713
1397226479.00875 -> 4.497471439365472
Task(<wrapper>)<result=(1397226479.00875, 1397226483.274884)> 4.266134023666382
Task(<wrapper>)<result=(1397226479.00875, 1397226479.6697)> 0.6609499454498291
Task(<wrapper>)<result=(1397226479.00875, 1397226482.844265)> 3.835515022277832
Task(<wrapper>)<result=(1397226479.00875, 1397226481.562422)> 2.5536720752716064
Task(<wrapper>)<result=(1397226479.00875, 1397226483.51523)> 4.506479978561401
= random_sleep.__name__: 'random_sleep' =
= random_sleep().__name__: 'wrapper' =
```

As you can see `random_sleep()` returns a generator object with different name. I would like to retain the name of the decorated coroutine. I am not aware if this is problem is specific to `asyncio.coroutines` or not. I also tried the code with different decorator orders, but all has the same result. If I comment `@functools.wraps(coro)` then even `random_sleep.__name__` becomes `wrapper` as I expected.

EDIT: I've posted this issue to Python Issue Tracker and received the following answer by R. David Murray: "I think this is a specific case of a more general need to improve 'wraps' that was discussed on python-dev not too long ago."

Comment: You could probably manage to save the name you want in your own variable, as a workaround. To be clear, the behavior you want is that `wrapper.__name__` must be 'wrapper', and not just that you want that value from somewhere?

Comment: As you can see, `asyncio.Task().__repr__()` includes the name of the generator object (`random_sleep().__name__`) which remained `wrapper`. Although I decorated the wrapper with `@functools.wraps` it only copied the name to the function level, but as soon as the function gets called by the Task the resulted generator object does not inherit that name. This meens that all Tasks containing `@time_resulted` coroutines represent themselves containing a `wrapper` coroutine which makes understanding tracebacks and error checking alot harder. [Link to the Issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21205)

Comment: I think you've raised a good issue and it seems like you will get more help from that than from here. Upvoted your question anyway. (Who knows? There are some really smart Python developers on SO.)

Comment: It isn't a case anymore for python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `functools.wraps` changes only `wrapper.__name__` and `wrapper().__name__` stays `wrapper`. `__name__` is a readonly generator attribute. You could use `exec` to set appropriate name:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import uuid
from textwrap import dedent

def wrap_coroutine(coro, name_prefix='__' + uuid.uuid4().hex):
    """Like functools.wraps but preserves coroutine names."""
    # attribute __name__ is not writable for a generator, set it dynamically
    namespace = {
        # use name_prefix to avoid an accidental name conflict
        name_prefix + 'coro': coro,
        name_prefix + 'functools': functools,
        name_prefix + 'asyncio': asyncio,
    }
    exec(dedent('''
        def {0}decorator({0}wrapper_coro):
            @{0}functools.wraps({0}coro)
            @{0}asyncio.coroutine
            def {wrapper_name}(*{0}args, **{0}kwargs):
                {0}result = yield from {0}wrapper_coro(*{0}args, **{0}kwargs)
                return {0}result
            return {wrapper_name}
        ''').format(name_prefix, wrapper_name=coro.__name__), namespace)
    return namespace[name_prefix + 'decorator']
```

Usage:

```
def time_resulted(coro):
    @wrap_coroutine(coro)
    def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
        # ...
    return wrapper
```

It works but there is probably a better way than using `exec()`.

Answer (score 3):

In the time since this question was asked, it became possible to change the name of a coroutine. It is done by setting `__qualname__` (not `__name__`):

```
async def my_coro(): pass

c = my_coro()
print(repr(c))
# <coroutine object my_coro at 0x7ff8a7d52bc0>

c.__qualname__ = 'flimflam'
print(repr(c))
# <coroutine object flimflam at 0x7ff8a7d52bc0>

import asyncio
print(repr(asyncio.ensure_future(c)))
# <Task pending name='Task-737' coro=<flimflam() running at <ipython-input>:1>>
```

The usage of `__qualname__` in a coroutine object's `__repr__` is defined [in the CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c6619552d2d4599458265dd5d24426ef545198d/Objects/genobject.c#L931-L936)

Comment: Might also be relevant: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/coro.html#c.PyCoro_New  and  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py#L52